# iOS 9 Error AKBooster

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I am getting the following error when downloading my Audio Kit application onto my iPad 2: AURemoteIO::IOThread (7): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0). However, when I change the AudioKit.output to modulin, it works. This would lead to me to beleive that the problem lies in the AKBooster applied to the voltageControlledAmplifer. Is there any specific order of AudioKit configuration that I am not following?

```
public var modulin: AKOperationGenerator!
public var voltageControlledAmplifier: AKBooster!
public var recordingNode: AKMixer!

private var recorder: AKNodeRecorder!
private var player: AKAudioPlayer?

private let midi = AKMIDI()
public var midiChannelIn: MIDIChannel = MIDIChannel(UserDefaults.midiChannel)
private var currentlySelectedMidiNotes = Set<MIDINoteNumber>()

// MARK: Init

init() {
    setUpAudioKit()
    setUpMidi()
}

// MARK: Private Functions

private func setUpAudioKit() {
    modulin = AKOperationGenerator.modulin()
    modulin.start()
    voltageControlledAmplifier = AKBooster(modulin, gain: 1)

    AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    AKSettings.bufferLength = AKSettings.BufferLength(rawValue: UserDefaults.preferredBufferSize)!
    AKSettings.sampleRate = UserDefaults.preferredSampleRate

    do {
        try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetooth, .mixWithOthers])

        recordingNode = AKMixer(voltageControlledAmplifier)
        // Recording Node and AudioKit Output must be the same
        AudioKit.output = recordingNode
        recorder = try AKNodeRecorder(node: recordingNode)

        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        print("AudioKit failed to set itself up.")
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong to my eyes.  Can you share the project either publicly or privately? Also, what version of AudioKit are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of AudioKit 4.2. I invited you to collaborate on a GitHub repository called Modulin through your GitHub username.

Comment: Your demo code that you shared with me seems to be working fine off of the develop branch of AudioKit for me.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I ran it on my iPad 2 and it crashed. Its working fine on iOS 11, just not iOS 9.

Comment: I put more instructions in the README.md.